# How do I search multiple contacts with one search query?

Tags: search

Let's say there are two contacts:

1. Jim Snow
2. Jon Newton

On the Salesforce lightning contact dashboard's search box, I want to search both of them like

Search : Jim && Jon

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using standard functionality (where? a list view?) or building something in Lightning?

Comment: It's on a list view, and I just want to know if it's possible, it's yes, then how

Answer (score 0):

You cannot type this kind of query into any out-of-the-box Salesforce search feature and get the behavior you desire.

You can construct [List Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_lex.htm&type=5) that filter records according to compound search criteria, which would allow you to achieve this type of search.